# CKEditor and FMElfinder : upload image symfony backend

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

I am under symfony 3, I installed Ivory CKEditor Bundle and FMElfinderBundle in order to upload images from CKEditor. [Here is the page I read](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/ckeditor-integration.md).

My worry is that I do not know where to place (in what CKEditor file) this piece of code:

```
// applies to Ivory CKEditor Bundle
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('content', 'ckeditor', array('config' => array('filebrowserBrowseRoute' => 'elfinder','filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters' => array('instance' => 'default','homeFolder' => '') ), ),))->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't updated so here what you do in symfony3 you add that in your form type, also take a look at the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html)

```
use Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

->add('content', CKEditorType::class, array(
        'config' => array(
            'filebrowserBrowseRoute' => 'elfinder',
            'filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters' => array(
                'instance' => 'default',
                'homeFolder' => ''
            )
        ),
    ),
))
```

And if you like to use elfinder in all ckeditor form, just add the config [docs](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/ckeditor-integration.md)

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: elfinder
            filebrowserBrowseRouteParameters: []
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried the first solution, i actually have a file type field that appears, but it lacks the configuration i think ... 
For example, I have a 500 error for entities that do not have the field to which I add the file type field.
Another problem, I cant upload the files from my pc.

Comment: @an_user elfinder didn't use field for upload it's just a file manager, for the problem of uploading in config set debug true and open js console it will show the error, I think it's a folder permission error